# Display Content on multiple pages using PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic

In one of my Facebook Apps, I want to add the ability for the user to view the gifts that were sent to them, even after they have accepted them. The problem is, the page would be entirley too long if they were all displayed on one. How would I go about displaying up to 8 images per page. The probelm is, I don't know exactly how the second, third, etc pages are created to display.

What I want is just like a search engine. Display so many, then go to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the gifts they were sent in some database, right?

`SELECT` from that table 8 rows at a time. Use a `LIMIT` clause to specify that you want 8 rows, and from which row to start picking those 8.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

The offset is the page number, minus 1, multiplied by 8.

Ex for page 3:

```
SELECT gift_name FROM gifts WHERE user = ? LIMIT 16,8
```

Comment: Ok. But, where do the other pages come from? Would I specify a variable in the URL of the next button that tells the page to start at that number in the DB?

Comment: Yes. You probably noticed on search engines and everywhere else that has paging, the URL includes the page number, something like `?page=2`.

Comment: Cool. I guess it is pretty easy, huh? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a little trouble. I used the code to get the data from the DB, which worked great! However, I can't seem to get all the data... it only displays the first row for that user. Any ideas how to oop through the results?

Comment: Nice. I am surprised that this kind of questio did not get 1k upvotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a page identifier to detect page number. The page number should be 0,1,2,3..

Then multiply it with number of results per page to get starting row from where you want next 8 results.

For example you have a variable called **pageNumber** for current page .

A **limit** variable to get starting row.

```
    resultPerPage = 8; 
    limit =(pageNumber)*(resultPerPage);
```

Then the query will be

```
    SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE somevar = ? LIMIT limit , 8;
```

Now if your page number is 0 then **limit** will be 0 and if page number is 1 then limit will be 8 vice verse..